# What is this circuit component called, and how do I find it in LT Spice

Tags: ltspice

Hey guys I'm pretty new to Schematic drawing and I was just wondering what this kind of part is and where I could find it in LT Spice. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what an IC is?

Comment: It's an IC package?

Comment: It's called an LB1930, it says it right there on the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet is [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/ANDLB1930MC-D.PDF).

If there's any detail there you don't understand, edit your question to explain exactly what the problem is.

It's unlikely that LTspice has this as a library component, so you'll have to create your own, following the LTspice documentation.

Comment: And there's no guarantee it's in LTSpice.  LTSpice is designed to sell Linear Technology products, so there's not much coverage of parts that aren't made by Linear.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find it in LT spice, you get spice files from the manufacturer (I don't think on semi makes one for the LB1930) and then import them yourself. This [link shows you how to do import](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html).